# How to use timer to call the function using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, timer

In my phonegap android application, i need to communicate with the server for every 1 sec. So I have tried with the sample code.

Here is my code:

```
var timeIntervalId = 0;
timeIntervalId = window.setInterval ( "onload1()", 1000 );
function onload1()
{
  alert("hai");
}
```

It works fine when I am in the same page. But my problem is I need to call this timer function wherever I am in the whole application. Please Kindly Guide Me. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know about android but I here is my way that i can do in my web application...

simple solution is put this function in one javascript file and than form the `document.ready()` method or `windows.load` method of page call this function....this will work for you

or

you can put the code in the `doucment.ready()` function and that put whole code in one javascript file and than include this javascript file in all pages will do your work ....

`doucment.ready()` - is part of jQuery..